# SQL Server: Return records within X days of a date

Tags: sql-server

I need a WHERE condition in SQL Server where I can return the past 7 days of activity from a given date.

Pretend I have 2 columns of dates [dateA] and [dateB]

I am looking for something like

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE [dateB] >= ([dateA] - 7 days)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WHERE dateB >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, dateA)
```

[Potentially useful reading](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187081%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)...

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table
where dateB >= dateadd(dd,-7, dateA)
```

Comment: Why use `dd` instead of just spelling out `DAY` and being clearer? Please read: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE [dateB]) >= convert(datetime,[dateA] - 7)

You were so close

Comment: I recommend against shorthand like `datetime - n` - this fails with new types like `DATE` and `DATETIME2`. https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
    IF you need past 7 days activity then you need take difference of date in that column from today i.e GETDATE() it will be something like this......

 WHERE (DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), dateA) <= 0 AND DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), dateA) > -7 ) 
        AND (DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), dateB) <= 0 AND DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), dateB) > -7 )
```

Comment: to get values from past 7 days you have to take date difference from today, ColumnA and ColumnB can have any values, if the column you taking difference from doesnt have todays's date you will not have data for past 7 days.

Comment: For something simple like getting results from the past year, you can use: WHERE (DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), DateColumn) > -365 )